# JAVA Selenium - getting hrefs from html in a loop

Tags: java, html, selenium, for-loop, href

I'm trying to get hrefs of few similiar elements on the page and then find the last created (max) id in these hrefs. I have got a loop but it only finds the first element and does not search for the rest of them. Do you know what's written wrong in it?

```
ArrayList<Integer> tablicas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
        String s = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.linkOffer")).getAttribute("href");
        String p = s.substring(19, s.length());             
        int numer = Integer.parseInt(p);    
        System.out.print(p);

        for(int indeks : tablicas) {
            if(indeks == numer) {
                continue;
            } else {
                tablicas.add(numer);
        }
        }
        } System.out.print(tablicas);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code snippet.

driver.FindElement() will return one WebElement. - Since your css selector is identincal for each iteration of the loop, it will always return the same WebElement.

Change your loop to something like this:

```
for(WebElement el : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.linkOffer"))) {
    String target =  el.getAttribute("href");        
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the all the elements which contains text 'Nowa oferta dokument', use `driver.findElements`(which will return list of elements matching your search criteria) rather than `findElement` and loop through the all elements.

```
ArrayList<Integer> tablicas = new ArrayList<Integer>();

java.util.List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='Nowa oferta dokument']"));

for(WebElement element : elements)
{
 element.getAttribute("href");
 String p = s.substring(19, s.length());             
 int numer = Integer.parseInt(p);    
 System.out.print(p);

 for(int indeks : tablicas) {
  if(indeks == numer) {
    continue;
   } 
  else {
    tablicas.add(numer);
   }
 }
}
System.out.print(tablicas);
```

Hope this helps.